# Can a Docker localhost and React Native Metro server both running on different ports communicate?

Tags: react-native, docker, networking, localhost

Hopefully somebody can clarify this for me;

I have an API running in a Docker container with a binded port on `8081`.
I then have my React Native metro server/app running on port `8899`.

I want to call the API running on localhost:8081 in my React Native app.
To do so, do I need to do anything to make sure the two can communicate? i.e. port forwarding etc.

**Example**

```
.fetch('GET', 'http://localhost:8081/get_something', {
    accept: 'application/x-wifi-config',
    'content-Type': 'application/xml',
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start docker by exposing that port to host with command line option "-p 8081:8081" to "docker run"  command.

Comment: Yes, this is the step I missed yesterday.  Figured it out 5 minutes before finishing up.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the example doesn't work, try to change the localhost with your actual IP.